# Is there an Xcode code completion shortcut to jump through noncontiguous function names?

Tags: xcode

I want to be able to select a table view delegate method with the least amount of characters possible.

Let say I want to implement the

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
```

So I start typing "t". Code completion kicks in and gives me a nice selection.

Is there a way to somehow "jump" to red highlighted character position (I chose "d" but it's about the position..not that particular "d")  after I type "t" and since I want the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: I would type "h" and the method would be selected?

[image]

Comment: File an enhancement request.

Answer (score 4):

*Update:*

Now Xcode 7 ships with the fuzzy autocompletion by default

*Previous answer:*

Sadly no. It was hinted that Xcode 7 might implement a fuzzy autocomplete engine, but so far we have to use a third party solution:
[Fuzzy autocomplete](https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin)
I've been using it for a while and works great. You can install it with [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io/), if you are familiar with it.

Comment: one and the best answer

Comment: I use AppCode simultaniously with Xcode to get this functionality